# How can I find out what test type is being executed?

Tags: grails, testing, grails-2.3

I've written a plugin to do data migrations under mongodb which inserts test data under a test context (like liquibase does) but the test data is interfering with my functional tests.

I was thinking rather than applying the test data during the test context, I could insert when the test type is 'migration' also.

Within Grails, how do I determine the current test type that is executing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the variables `currentTestPhaseName` and `currentTestTypeName` from the  delegate binding (`GantBinding`). If you are in `_Events.groovy` you can directly access them from an event closure. If you are inside a `GrailsTestTypeSupport` there is a member `buildBinding`.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think those exist anymore in 2.3. But you gave me the idea to dig deeper into _GrailsTest.groovy and it seems targetPhasesAndTypes exists and gives me what I need.

Comment: Strange, I checked it with grails 2.4.0 and it worked, no idea why you don't have them.